# Is there a way to create an an automatic email if someone is removed from a group?

Tags: email, groups, activity

I looked at scheduled activities hoping I could use that but alas it doesn't seem like it.

I could create a database trigger but that's a bit work.

Answer (score 6):

I think this should be possible with using the [CiviRules extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/).

Comment: Yes you can :-)

Comment: Apparently you also need to install the E-mail API extension, which as far as I can tell isn't mentioned anywhere in the CiviRules docs.